# when I am using this comparator function without static keyword it giving error

Tags: c++, static, std-pair

I am writing a comparator function to sort according to second element. But it throwing error when I use this without static keyword.

```
bool cmp(pair<int,int> a, pair<int,int> b){
        return (a.second < b.second);
    }
```

**ERROR**

> In member function int Solution::maxMeetings(int*, int*, int):
> prog.cpp:24:37: error: invalid use of non-static member function
> sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);

Comment: You cannot use non-static member function in this manner as the sort comparator.  Either make the function static, create a function object, or use a lambda (there are other ways, but you simply can't pass a non-static member function).

Comment: Member functions aren't the same as regular functions (unless they are static).

Comment: Put it this way, you as passing a pointer to `cmp` to `sort`. But `cmp` is a member function so it can only be called with a `Solution` object. Since you do not pass any `Solution` object to `sort` how can it call `cmp`? Of course if `cmp` is static then you do not need a `Solution` object to call it, so the problem is solved.

Comment: [more on static member functions here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/static-member-functions/)